# Missing files have disappeared

Tags: files, data-recovery, filemanager

I extracted my files from a memory card and put them in a folder, formatted my memory card, and after restart the files are not in the folder on the hard disk. Is there a way to return them?

I didn't create symbolic links, nor shortcuts.
I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>---><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
The folder is still there, but there is nothing inside of it.

Comment: I used CTR-C -> CTRL-V

Comment: I didn't create symbolic links, nor shortcuts.

Comment: Are you sure the folder you put them in was not on the memory card? Computers tend to not forget stuff that easily.

Comment: See [How to recover deleted files?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files) and apply to the memory card. Best of luck.

Comment: Use the shell, Luke! The GNU coreutils like `cp` and `ls` are used by many distros (and on non-Linux Unixes, and even Windows via Cygwin and MinGW).  The Ubuntu file manager is specific to Ubuntu.

Comment: "After a restart the files are not in the folder ..." was it a clean shutdown and reboot? How soon after the copy operation did you pull out the memory card, and did you cleanly unmount it? How soon did you restart the system?